# Dependent SDK initialization

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

I've a service (ProductService) that uses an SDK (SDK 1) created by me. SDK 1 is dependent on a second SDK (SDK 2) again created by me.

let's say SDK 1 has following service

```
public SDK1Service (SDK1Interface1 interface1, SDK1Interface2 interface2, SDK2Interface3 interface3)
{
    //initialization
}
SDK1Class1 implements SDK1Interface1
SDK1Class2 implements SDK1Interface2
```

SDK 2 has following service

```
public SDK2Service (SDK2Interface3 interface3, SDK2Interface4 interface4)
{
    //initialization
}
SDK2Class3 implements SDK2Interface3
SDK2Class4 implements SDK2Interface4
```

SDK1 and SDK2 will be used by a Service, let's say ProductService.

**How should ProductService initialize SDK1 and SDK2??**

1. Dependency injection in Program.cs of ProductService that will initialize SDK1 and SDK2.

```
    public class Program
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddTransient<SDK1Interface1, SDK1Class1>();
            //.......
        }
    }
```

2. Factory pattern that would initialize SDK1. Here there would be bulk initialization of services in ConfigureServices created through factory pattern.

```cs
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddTransient<ISDK1Factory, SDK1Factory>();
        //.......
    }
```

Factory

```
    public class SDK1Factory : ISDK1Factory
    {
        private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    
        public SDK1Factory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        }
    
        public SDK1Service CreateSDK1Service()
        {
            var interface1 = 
           _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<SDK1Interface1>();
            //...........
            return new SDK1Service(interface1, interface2, interface3);

        }
    }
```

3. SDK 2 Initialization logic in SDK 1. SDK 1 will pass the concrete class to ProductService. But this looks anti-pattern to me. initialization logic in SDK doesn't seem correct to me.

Comment: Please clarify (maybe with some sample code) what you mean by "factory pattern".

Comment: With the information provided there is no reason why one should avoid IoC or Factory.  If you don't have anything that prevents IoC, go with it (#1).  Note:  You have the IoC statement backwards:  The interface goes first.

Comment: @MichaelLiu By Factory pattern, I meant design pattern for instance creation. I've added code for clarity.

Comment: @JoséRamírez Thank you for pointing out. I'm trying to minimize the changes that the ProductService would require if I want to make changes in the SDK 1 and SDK2. further more, I'm also thinking of ways to abstract SDK 2 from Product Service.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying.  You then seem to have asked the question incorrectly.  You don't want to know if IoC or factory is better:  You want to know how you could make ProductService dependant on only one SDK.  The thing here is:  I see no point in the exercise.  Your service should consume what it needs.  The procedence of the dependency should be of no concern to anyone as long as it can be provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of those three options is ideal:

1. Option 1 requires ProductService to hardcode too many details about SDK1 and SDK2.
2. Option 2 uses the Service Locator anti-pattern in the factory.
3. You didn't provide sample code for Option 3, but it sounds like SDK1 will need to hardcode too many details about SDK2.

Instead, I would adopt the approach taken by many .NET packages: Each SDK provides its own AddSdk extension method that registers the respective SDK's services as well as any SDK dependencies.

SDK2 would provide the following:

```
public static class Sdk2ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static void AddSdk2(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddTransient<SDK1Interface3, SDK1Class3>();
        services.AddTransient<SDK1Interface4, SDK1Class4>();
    }
}
```

SDK1, which depends on SDK2, would provide the following:

```
public static class Sdk1ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static void AddSdk1(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSdk2();
        services.AddTransient<SDK1Interface1, SDK1Class1>();
        services.AddTransient<SDK1Interface2, SDK1Class2>();
    }
}
```

And, assuming that SDK2 is an internal implementation detail of SDK1 and not used directly by ProductService, ProductService would just call `AddSdk1` at startup:

```
public class Program
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSdk1();
    }
}
```

Comment: This does make sense. Basically, we are pushing the instantiation logic to SDK itself. Looks much better approach.